# Split vector to multiple vectors

Tags: matlab

I'm looking for a simple method to transforming a vector of the following type 
[1   1   0   1   1]

To this group of vectors:

```
[0 0 0 0 1]
[0 0 0 1 0]
[0 1 0 0 0]
[1 0 0 0 0]
```

The vector itself represents polynomial coefficients (x^4  + x^3  + x + 1)

Thanks

Comment: Should the output be a matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some approaches. Input is a vector `v`, output is a matrix `M`:

---

```
[~, rr, vv] = find(v);
M = full(sparse(1:nnz(v), flip(rr), 1));
```

---

```
M = flip(eye(numel(v)));
M = M(logical(v),:)
```

---

```
M = zeros(nnz(v), numel(v));
M(sub2ind(size(M), 1:size(M,1), flip(find(v)))) = 1;
```

---

```
M = double(bsxfun(@eq, flip(find(v(:))), 1:numel(v)));
```